# what is the time complexity of this recursive function in python?

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity

I have this function:

```
def rec(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return rec(lst[n // 2:]) + rec(lst[:n // 2])
```

How can I find the time complexity of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in such problems drawing the recursion tree helps.

[image]

Look at this photo I added, note how each level sums up to N (since slicing is the thing here doing the work),
and the depth of the tree is logN (this is easy to show, since we divide by 2 each time, you can find an explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/complexity-analysis-of-binary-search/)). So what we have is the function doing `O(n)` `n*logn` times which means in total we have `O(n*logn)`.

Now another way of understanding this is using the "[Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))" (I encourage you to look it up and learn about it)
We have here `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)`, so according to the theorem `a=2, b=2` so `log_b(a)` is equal to 1, and therefore
we have (according to the 2nd case of the theorem):

`T(n)=O(logn*(n**(log_b(a)))=O(nlogn)`